# How to accuse someone of lying

Tags: words

うそだ isn't really a serious accusation. How would you say 'you're lying' more seriously?

Comment: Hmm.... 「うそつけっ！」, maybe? or 「うそつき！」とか・・

Comment: How about 「嘘つくんじゃねえぞ、このやろう」(笑)

Comment: Users keep answering questions in the comment section.

Comment: [Isn't it serious?](http://knowyourmeme.com/memes/uso-da-%E5%98%98%E3%81%A0) :D

Answer (score 1):

The answer @Unknown gave is perfect if you want more weight and directness to the accusation

> Hmm.... 「うそつけっ！」, maybe? or 「うそつき！」とか・・ –  Unknown May 21 at 22:04

Comment: What do you not understand? [うそつけ！](http://www.alc.co.jp/jpn/article/faq/03/113.html) or うそをつけ is the imperative form of うそ(を)つく, and うそつき！ means "(You're) a liar!"

Comment: (あっ　コメント消えてるやん・・・。↑あほみたいやん、私。。。)

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that うそだ is already strong enough, when said in normal tone (or more serious, of course), because we don't usually use in that way.  Another possible strong expression would be

> それはない。 (That can't be true.)

Perhaps you should compare with more casual accusing expressions such as う(っ)そだ〜 うそでしょ？

Comment: Note that それはない doesn't imply someone is lying.

Comment: Logically speaking, it does not imply that someone is lying, because it can be used to point out someone's statement is untrue, regardless of his/her intention.  But still it could be used to strongly insist that he/she is wrong, or telling a lie.

Comment: Yes, my point was that its emphasis is on the *wrong* (or unlikely) part, not its being a lie or not.